# Filtering the space the space to the end of the string while retaining special charecter at same position

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic

I have a string **(  )  -   (  )**    where "(",")" and "-" are special characters in the string. Here the string separates the character with white space. When the user enters the characters between the string white space is replaced with inputs. Then the string looks **"(9  )  -8 ( 7 )"**. 
 I need to put all the input to left most side with retaining the special characters at same positions and pushing the space to the end of the string. Then the string will look like this **(987)  -  (  )**. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with. Which seems working for now

```
var value = "(9 ) -8 ( 7 )";
        for (var i = 0; i < mask.length; i++) {
            var char = mask.charAt(i);
            if ('9XA'.indexOf(char) != -1) {
                if (value.charAt(i) == " ") {
                    var j = i + 1;
                    var matchPattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/                        
                    while (value.length)
                        if (value.charAt(j).match(matchPattern) || value.charAt(i) == " ")
                            break;
                        else
                            j++;
                    var temp = value.charAt(i);
                    value.charAt(i) = value.charAt(j);
                    value = value.insert(i, value.charAt(j));
                    value = value.insert(j, temp);
                }
            }
        }
```